# Why We setAttribute ? What is done by setAttribute() function?

Tags: php, pdo, setattribute

[image]

Why We setAttribute ? What is done by setAttribute() function?

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of image.

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: did you refer it before implement code?

Answer (score 0):

The [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.setattribute.php) function sets an attribute to a value.

In your case, you are setting the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` (error reporting) of the database connection as `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` (throw exceptions).